# Terraform ALB error "Error creating LB Listener Rule: Priority X is currently in use" when changing rule hostname

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When trying to change hostname in existing ALB rule, always getting an error:

*"Error creating LB Listener Rule: PriorityInUse: Priority '40' is currently in use"*

Tried recommendations from [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/636) but nothing helps. Tried not specifying name for TargetGroup, using create_before_destroy, random strings for a name, etc. Terraform version 0.10.7, AWS provider 1.54.0 (tried also 2.10.0)

On a subsequent Terraform apply, the change is applied.

TF config:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "rule1" {
  depends_on = ["aws_lb_target_group.tg1"]
    lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  listener_arn = "${aws_lb_listener.listener.arn}"
  priority = "40"
  action {
    type             = "forward"
  target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.tg1.id}"
  }
  condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["www.hostname.com"]
  }
  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/STATIC"]
  }
}



resource "aws_lb_target_group" "tg1" {
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
port = "443"
protocol = "HTTPS"
vpc_id   = "${var.vpc_id}"
health_check {
interval = "10"
path = "/"
  port= "443"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  timeout = "9"
  healthy_threshold  = "5"
  unhealthy_threshold  = "3"
  }
  tags {
    Name = "${terraform.workspace}-service1"
   }
}
```

I would expect that once you change a hostname in ALB rule, Terraform will handle that change without issues, but looks like it's trying to re-create ALB rule with new hostname but with the same priority number, and hence it fails. After running terraform apply again, it does the change.

There might be workarounds to check existing ALB rule Priority name and specify a new/different one, but that should be handled natively by Terraform as otherwise we would need to keep track of priority numbers to avoid clashes.

Did anyone had same issue and resolved it somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue is happening because of the way I was provisioning new ALB rule resources; every time I was creating TF ALB rule resource with new resource name (rule2, rule3, etc) which was clashing with existing priority number. So the solution is to either have new priority number in new resource, or leave resource name the same every time (rule1) in which case Terraform handles the change properly.

Comment: In my case I already have priority LB, I just change that resource ```"aws_lb_listener_rule" "api" {
  priority     = 20
...}```  where 20 is any available lb priority

Comment: In which file ?

Comment: I am not sure, but is this related to the following github issue? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/636
I had a similar problem, and a selective ```terraform destroy -target ...``` targeted at the aws_lb_listener_rule, followed by a selective ```terraform apply -target ...```fixed it.